# Getting "Error: Could not find or load class" even though I have the Main-class defined in a Manifest File

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to build a jar file through the command line, and I'm running into issues.

Here are the contents of my jar file:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
bin/main/Main.class
```

and the contents of my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: bin.main.Main
```

This seems to me like it should work, but when I try to run the jar file on command line using

`java -jar -JAR.jar`

I'm told

**`**Error: Could not find or load main class bin.main.Main**`**

Comment: You are sure the package is bin.main?

Comment: The package declaration for Main.java is package main; Is there no way to make the jar work with the current directory structure? I want to keep the Main.java file in src/main/ and the Main.class file in bin/main

Comment: @Lifus If the package is `main`, the class file **must** be put into `/main/Main.class` (not `/bin/main/Main.class`).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Right now my Main.java file is in 

src/main/Main.java

If I try to compile it with javac src/main/Main.java the .class file gets placed in the same directory as the .java file. But if I try to tell the compiler to put the class file somewhere else, using javac -d main src/main/Main.java, the class file gets placed in main/main/Main.class. 

How can I keep .class and .java files in separate directories while keeping the proper package structure?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Main.java has `package bin.main;` on the first line.

Seelenvirtuose adds that if the package is main, the class file must be put into `/main/Main.class` (not `/bin/main/Main.class`).

Comment: The package declaration for Main.java is package main;

Is there no way to make the jar work with the current directory structure? I want to keep the Main.java file in src/main/ and the Main.class file in bin/main

Comment: @Lifus That doesn't work, because that is simply not valid for Java. You will need to accept that Java's jar file format requires packages to be rooted in `/`, not in `/bin/`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Huh, is there no way then to keep .class and .java files in separate directories?

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with your problem. You would normally not include sources in a Jar file. It sounds like you are compiling 'in situ'. Normally you compile to a build folder (eg with javac -d <folder>), and use that build folder to create the jar (or better yet: use a build tool like Maven or Gradle to do it for you).

Comment: Well, if I try to compile to a build folder, by using javac -d build src/main/Main.java then the result is build/main/Main.class

If I try to turn that into a jar file, using jar cfm JAR.jar src/META-INF/MANIFEST.mf build/main/*.class I am left with a Jar file with 

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
build/main/Main.class

Which doesn't work since it has to have 
main/Main.class